# How to increment cumulative max

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column (price) whose values change over time. From one row to another, the value increases, decreases or stays the same. I want to record how many times the value reached a new high.

So, I added a column `currenthigh` which keeps track of the highest value so far. Then I added another column `currenthigh_prev` which is the `currenthigh` column shifted by one row. This way, I can compare both values: the current and the previous. If `currenthigh > currenthigh_prev` then I have a new high, which is recorded in `newhighscount`.

I have been trying to use `.cummax()` for this, which seemed appropriate.

```
df.loc[df['currenthigh'] > df['currenthigh_shift'], 'newhighscount'] = df['newhighscount'].cummax() + 1
```

I was expecting this :

```
              datetime      last  currenthigh  currenthigh_shift  **newhighscount** 
31 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8400       389.84                NaN              0 
32 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8400       389.84             389.84              0 
33 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8700       389.87             389.84              **1** 
34 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8800       389.88             389.87              **2** 
35 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.9000       389.90             389.88              **3** 
36 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.9600       389.96             389.90              **4** 
37 2019-04-02 07:57:35  389.9000       389.96             389.96              **4** 
38 2019-04-02 07:57:36  389.9000       389.96             389.96              **4** 
39 2019-04-02 08:00:00  389.3603       389.96             389.96              **4** 
40 2019-04-02 08:00:00  388.8500       389.96             389.96              **4** 
41 2019-04-02 08:00:00  390.0000       390.00             389.96              **5** 
42 2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.7452       390.00             390.00              **5** 
43 2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.4223       390.00             390.00              5 
44 2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.8000       390.00             390.00              5
```

And I am getting this:

```
              datetime      last  currenthigh  currenthigh_shift  newhighscount 
31 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8400       389.84                NaN              0 
32 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8400       389.84             389.84              0 
33 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8700       389.87             389.84              1 
34 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8800       389.88             389.87              1 
35 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.9000       389.90             389.88              1 
36 2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.9600       389.96             389.90              1 
37 2019-04-02 07:57:35  389.9000       389.96             389.96              0 
38 2019-04-02 07:57:36  389.9000       389.96             389.96              0 
39 2019-04-02 08:00:00  389.3603       389.96             389.96              0 
40 2019-04-02 08:00:00  388.8500       389.96             389.96              0 
41 2019-04-02 08:00:00  390.0000       390.00             389.96              1 
42 2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.7452       390.00             390.00              0 
43 2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.4223       390.00             390.00              0 
44 2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.8000       390.00             390.00              0
```

Basically, the `df['newhighscount'].cummax()` doesn't seem to return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df['newhighscount'] = df['last'].cummax().diff().gt(0).cumsum()
```

This calculates the cumulative maximum of the last column, calculates the difference (cummax_t - cummax_{t-1}), checks if the difference is greater than zero and counts the number of times this has been true.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: What if I want to start the count only after a certain time, say 8:00? I already have another bool column which is True when it is after 8:00 and False otherwise.

Comment: You can use: `df.loc[df['yourboolcol'], 'newhighscount2'] = df.loc[df['yourboolcol'], 'last'].cummax().diff().gt(0).cumsum()`. Keep in mind this will leave `NaN`s in the rows where your boolean column is false.

Comment: Thanks. It works almost fine: the first new high is not taken into account. Still trying to figure out why..

Comment: Actually `df['newhighscount2'] = (df['last'].cummax().diff().gt(0) & df['yourboolcol'].shift(1)).cumsum()` might be more elegant. The shift is there to move the first true to the second price value, so you don't get a newhigh in your first record. In case you want your first value (after 8) to be able to count as a new high, you can remove the shift.

Comment: This actually doesn't work as well as your previous answer. The count starts at the 6th increment. No big deal, I'll figure it out!

Comment: Is the 6th increment the 1st after 8?

Comment: I meant the 1st increment after 8:00. My code is supposed to count the number of increments in the 'last' column since your boolean column has been true, which I guess is true if the time is after 8:00. It should have zeros all the way down to the first increment after 8:00.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is indeed the first increment after 8. And it does work fine actually, not sure what I had messed up (still doesn't take the first new high into account, but no problem).

Comment: Try removing the shift. The shift is there so that if your last value before 8:00 is lower than your first value after 8:00 it doesn't count as an increment, because technically the values after 8:00 haven't increased. If you want this to actually count as an increment you can remove the shift and it will capture it.

Comment: Well, surprisingly, the output is the same with or without the shift...

Comment: Can you edit the question to include this new problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to label unique `'currenthigh'` values. There are many ways to do this:

### `ngroup`

```
df['NewCount'] = df.groupby('currenthigh', sort=False).ngroup()
```

#### `rank`:

Will work here since `cummax` is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing.

```
df['NewCount'] = (df.currenthigh.rank(method='dense')-1).astype(int)
```

### `map`

```
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.Series.unique(df.currenthigh) # Preserves order
df['NewCount'] = df.currenthigh.map(dict((arr[i], i) for i in range(len(arr))))
```

#### Output:

```
                         last  currenthigh  NewCount
datetime                                            
2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8400       389.84         0
2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8400       389.84         0
2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8700       389.87         1
2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.8800       389.88         2
2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.9000       389.90         3
2019-04-02 07:57:33  389.9600       389.96         4
2019-04-02 07:57:35  389.9000       389.96         4
2019-04-02 07:57:36  389.9000       389.96         4
2019-04-02 08:00:00  389.3603       389.96         4
2019-04-02 08:00:00  388.8500       389.96         4
2019-04-02 08:00:00  390.0000       390.00         5
2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.7452       390.00         5
2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.4223       390.00         5
2019-04-02 08:00:01  389.8000       390.00         5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I am going to study it. I am new here and honestly I did not know which answer to accept, yours or josemz's...

Comment: What if I want to start the count only after a certain time, say 8:00? I already have another bool column which is True when it is after 8:00 and False otherwise. (I also asked the accepted answer's author...).

Comment: @fredericf then you should be able to slice the RHS and just assign back. You can then choose to keep the others `NaN` or `.fillna(0)`. I.e. something like `df['NewCount'] = df[Bool_Series].groupby('currenthigh', sort=False).ngroup()`. Luckily you seem to have a MultiIndex, so it wont have issues with the duplicated times, when trying to align.

Comment: Ok. I'll study this too. May I ask how you could format my dataframe in the question?

Comment: @fredericf format it as a code block with the `{}` button in the editor. So highlight it all and then this will indent everything 4 lines, which gives it the nice formatting.

Comment: Great. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***: *base on your data, a single command below would be enough*

```
df['newhighscount'] = (df['currenthigh'] > df['currenthigh_shift']).astype(int).cumsum()
```

**Original:**
You logic still works, but it's not elegant as the other answers. It just needs a little bit twist.

```
In [983]: df
Out[983]:
               datetime      last  currenthigh  currenthigh_shift   newhighscount
31 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8400       389.84                NaN               0
32 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8400       389.84             389.84               0
33 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8700       389.87             389.84               0
34 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8800       389.88             389.87               0
35 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.9000       389.90             389.88               0
36 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.9600       389.96             389.90               0
37 2019-04-02  07:57:35  389.9000       389.96             389.96               0
38 2019-04-02  07:57:36  389.9000       389.96             389.96               0
39 2019-04-02  08:00:00  389.3603       389.96             389.96               0
40 2019-04-02  08:00:00  388.8500       389.96             389.96               0
41 2019-04-02  08:00:00  390.0000       390.00             389.96               0
42 2019-04-02  08:00:01  389.7452       390.00             390.00               0
43 2019-04-02  08:00:01  389.4223       390.00             390.00               0
44 2019-04-02  08:00:01  389.8000       390.00             390.00               0

In [985]: df.loc[df['currenthigh'] > df['currenthigh_shift'], 'newhighscount'] = (df['currenthigh'] > df['currenthigh_shift']).astype(int).cumsum()
In [989]: df['newhighscount'] = df['newhighscount'].cummax()
In [990]: df
Out[990]:
               datetime      last  currenthigh  currenthigh_shift  newhighscount
31 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8400       389.84                NaN              0
32 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8400       389.84             389.84              0
33 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8700       389.87             389.84              1
34 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.8800       389.88             389.87              2
35 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.9000       389.90             389.88              3
36 2019-04-02  07:57:33  389.9600       389.96             389.90              4
37 2019-04-02  07:57:35  389.9000       389.96             389.96              4
38 2019-04-02  07:57:36  389.9000       389.96             389.96              4
39 2019-04-02  08:00:00  389.3603       389.96             389.96              4
40 2019-04-02  08:00:00  388.8500       389.96             389.96              4
41 2019-04-02  08:00:00  390.0000       390.00             389.96              5
42 2019-04-02  08:00:01  389.7452       390.00             390.00              5
43 2019-04-02  08:00:01  389.4223       390.00             390.00              5
44 2019-04-02  08:00:01  389.8000       390.00             390.00              5
```

Comment: Thank andy, it works. Now I have to understand how :-)

Comment: it is simple, so I think you will figure it out really fast. Let's me know if you need any pointer. 
By the way, base on your data, this single command `df['newhighscount'] = (df['currenthigh'] > df['currenthigh_shift']). astype(int).cumsum()` would suffice